# How to check that two dropdown lists is selected in angular2 and if it's true invoke some method?

Tags: angular, typescript, select, drop-down-menu, handler

I have a two drop down list and I want to check that if a user has selected vaue in both lists and if both selected invoke method that will recieve two values from each list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can improve the logic if you give your html and component code .

Have two booleans for both the check boxes .

```
private val1Changed= false;
private val2Changed = false; 

public val1ChangeHandler(){
    this.val1Changed= true;
    this.performAction();
}
public val2ChangeHandler(){
    this.val2Changed= true;
    this.performAction();
}

public performAction(){
     if(!(this.val1Changed && this.val2Changed)){
         return;
     }
     // perform some action 

     // Reset values after action is successfully performed 
     this.val1Changed = false;
     this.val2Changed = false;
}
```

Add `val1ChangeHandler` and  `val2ChangeHandler`  in HTML `(change)` tag

Comment: Thanks a lot for idea!A little remade it for myself and it all worked!